# Ankh cannot commit changes with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: svn, ankhsvn, visual-studio-2010

I am in a big trouble with the Ankh plug in for visual studio 2010. I use VS 2010 RC using Ankh 2.1.7756.392. And every time I try to commit changes I get the following error:

SharpSvn.SvnException: Can't move '[solution path].svn\tmp\entries' to '[solution path].svn\entries': Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

I also use tortoise svn and it runs ok, but it's not very convenient to commit my changes with it. Also my team mate use the same software and it runs OK. He doesn't have any troubles at all. I tried reinstalling the plug-in - no help. Tried to delete my working copy and checkout everything again - no help again. The repository is run on separate server - not on my machine.

I could get any help with google, so I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

EDIT: Also I use Windows 7 and my working copy is on a mapped drive (using subst command). But my teammate is using the same way and it's working.

Comment: I think you'd get a better response asking this question on the Collabnet Community forums (http://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewForumSummary.do?dsForumId=4)

Comment: This question is asked there and there is no response. So I wonder if any of SO users have experienced similar problem. And I don't think that this question is by far related to programming! Who other use SVN and visual studio, besides programmers ?! And there is a whole bunch of questions regarding svn source control visual studio and etc. I don't agree with the close vote.

Comment: @Lazarus: the AnkhSVN specific list would've been even better: http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewForumSummary.do?dsForumId=582

Comment: @anthares, This isn't programming related. It wouldn't matter if the applications was AnkhSVN, MS Word, or Windows Explorer. App works on one machine, doesn't work on mine. That's application support and exactly what you got.

Comment: @Sander, perhaps I should have posted the question for them as well. You do realise there is no rep to be gained here, a waste of your time perhaps?

Comment: @Lazarus not everything on this site is for gaining rep. And I don't agree that my question is the only one regarding source control and should be labeled as "not programming related". But I will vote for closing too, just to make you happy.

Comment: @Lazarus, I wonder why helping someone can be a waste of time. I'm just pointing out the place where you're most likely to get help for this specific case, also for future reference. And I fully agree with @anthares that not everything on stack overflow is about reputation.

Comment: @anthares, I'm not asking for you to vote for the question to be closed. If you can explain to me how this is programming related then I'm more than happy to withdraw my objection.

Comment: @Sander, you didn't answer anthares, you directed your point at me; as if I had somehow failed them by not giving a specific location for them to find the answer. I've never found hand-holding to be an effective teaching method and always encourage initiative and deduction as these lead to skill in how to solve problems rather than just being able to regurgitate rote. If you disagree then that's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would have send your error to the AnkhSVN error list you would have received an automatic answer that this is a known issue for this specific version, but only on FAT and FAT32 filesystems which are generally not recommended for using as Subversion working copy anyway.
(Some changes in the second after the subversion operation completes can't be detected on these filesystems)

You can resolve this issue by upgrading to the daily builds available on http://ankhsvn.net/daily

Comment: Well I'm new to SVN and didn't know about this error list. I thought it is something like MS' send report for error. Thanks. If I move my working copy to NTFS will this problem go away ?

Comment: If you click 'send error' in the AnkhSVN error dialog it is send to our error list. And while we generally don't reply to all exceptions personally we use that list for gathering error statistics. We usually send more information about known issues that aren't handled in the client yet.

Comment: Yes, moving your working copy to NTFS will work around this (and it will also make AnkhSVN and other Subversion clients operate faster on your working copy)